# Bing Maps Infobox Pins stay on top

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ENN6.png

Heres my current problem 
The infobox appears under all the pins which isnt the best way to present an app to someone. 
I know theres ways to do this silverLight and html/css but Im using C# and Xaml for a Windows Store app.

Ive used the following tutorial to make the pushpins and infobox - http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/06/17/infoboxes-for-native-windows-store-apps.aspx

How Do I make the infobox appear on top?

Comment: Did you use both MapLayers like in the tutorial? And do you have them in the same order as in the tutorial? Can you show us the XAML you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding your pushpins to the DataLayer MapLayer like the code sample? That code sample uses two MapLayers, one for the InfoBox and the other for pushpins. The InfoBox layer is above the pin layer and should always appear above the pins.

Comment: I think I had that originally but then nothing was appearing. 
I changed to what it is now. I then changed to adding to the right layer and none of the pins appear which is odd (even if I hardcode one of them in C#)